# error about compiling multi files on vscode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compilation, project

I'm a beginner and I tried to run a simple project but received

```
o:main.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `max'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

I have searched on the Internet for hours but still failed. I really need your help. Thanks
my project :

1. my first try

I searched on the Internet and realized visual studio code compile one file one time. So I modify my tasks.json as follows

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe 生成活动文件",
            "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
//I modify the following sentences as
                "${fileDirname}\\function.c",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.c",
                "${fileDirname}\\main.h",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "调试器生成的任务。"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

But I still received

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZp5xjY.o:main.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `max'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

by the way, my project :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5k2Q.png)
and my settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZcDP.png)

2.my second try
I use the MakeFile but still the same error(another project but also a simple one)
MakeFile

```
sum : main.o sum.o
    gcc main.o sum.o -o sum
 
main.o : main.o sum.h
    gcc -c main.c
sum.o : sum.c sum.h
    gcc -c sum.c
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sum.h"
 
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", sum(8,3));
    // printf("1");
    return 0;
}
```

sum.c

```
#include "sum.h"
 
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

sum.h

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvlQ6.png)

so I doubt if I should adjust some settings of vscode

Comment: Adding headers to your compile command does not make any sense. They are included via `#include` directive and are not supposed to be compiled separately.

Comment: Are there more lines shown before that error message is printed?  Do you see a command line? Also I would assume that `"${file}"` contains the file in editor when you run compile command. Then you add `main.c` and `function.c` separately. That might add `main.c` twice causing more problems.

Comment: *I use the MakeFile but still the same error* Then please show content of that makefile.

Comment: the task shown does **NOT** use Make

Comment: thanks for answering, I just added the makefile in the post, it's based on another project but also a simple one

Comment: @Gerhardh here is the command line, sorry for some Chinese you may not know, but it's just file name
PS E:\vscode多文件编译> cd "e:\vscode多文件编译\" ; if ($?) { gcc main.c -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\ccAsc6eg.o:main.c:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to `max'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I can't really see how this command line is related to the `tasks.json` file you show above.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference errors happen when the compiler can't find the function that you are referencing. This is usually due to missing/incorrect arguments in one's Makefile.

I see you have a header file in the arguments of `tasks.json`, which is unnecessary.

EDIT: You did not put '-o' as an argument for main.o and sum.o You also put main.o as a required file for main.o, which wont work.

FIX:

```
sum: main.o sum.o
    gcc -o sum main.o sum.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -o main.o -c main.c
sum.o: sum.c
    gcc -o sum.o -c sum.c
```

Comment: I just added the makefile, could you please help me find the error? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just added an edit to my answer, which should give you results

Comment: thank you ,but still a new error undefined reference to `sum'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @itsagoodname I accidentally added mistakes to my answer, it should be worth looking at now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).